# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CLIENT_ENDPOINT for Amazon ECS

Tags: java, amazon-ecs

I tried to list the ECS clusters using the code as follow:

```
AmazonECS = amazonECS AmazonECSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build():
amazonECS.listClusters();
```

However, it gave the error

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: CLIENT_ENDPOINT

The error stack is something like this:

> com.amazonaws.services.ecs.AmazonECSClient in executeListClusters at
> line 2220 com.amazonaws.services.ecs.AmazonECSClient in listClusters
> at line 2202 com.amazonaws.services.ecs.AmazonECSClient in
> listClusters at line 2245

I am not too sure why this error occurred as the other Amazon services did not give me any similar error whatsoever and I have set the region previously based on the client's preference. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace for this error?

Comment: @NagarajTantri added in the question

Comment: Did you have a look at this github issue (similar in nature): https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2509#issuecomment-779370672? `NoSuchFieldError errors are usually caused by version mismatch between SDK modules. Ideally core and sts modules should be in the same version.`

Comment: @NagarajTantri thanks so much! I didnt realize that its caused by version mismatched

Comment: Hope it helped!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to [Nagaraj Trantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308565/nagaraj-tantri) the error is caused by the version mismatched of the AWS SDK that I have according to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2509#issuecomment-779370672

Comment: In my case, version of aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-core and aws-java-sdk-quicksight were not same.  Matched all three to latest one and issue resolved. Thanks

Comment: In my case, they were not the same, but when I made them same, the issue didn't resolve. But after I restarted my IDE it started working.

Answer (score 3):

Use this in the pom.xml file. Error is caused due to mismatch in the 'com.amazonaws' dependency versions declared in the pom.

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.739</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had different version for SQS and S3 in pom.xml. After I updated those to same versions, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where to look for these versions mismatch.

I am using spark to connect to secrets manager and thus we have 2 places to look at.

1. My Application dependencies (build.gradle)
2. spark.yarn.jars

The versions in the above 2 places should match and then it started working